# I am unable to get the text inside h2 tags, I have given my code below, if someone can help me in this matter, that will be very helpful

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Everything is good tillthe print vendor it finds all of the h2 in the particular div I want, but the issue that i am facing is that when I try to get the text of that h2 it gives me an error  i.e for y in vendor:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable . So if any one can help me it will be appreciated

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from csv import writer

soup = BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get(f"https://cognitiveclass.ai/search?q=data+science")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

for a_tag in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print('href: ', a_tag['href'])
    base_url = "https://cognitiveclass.ai"
        
        
    for a_tag in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
        print('-' * 60) # Add a line of dashes
        print('href: ', a_tag['href'])
        request_href = requests.get(base_url + a_tag['href'])
        soup = BeautifulSoup(request_href.text)
        div_title = soup.select('div', class_ = 'col-md-pull-4')
        #print(div_title)
        for x in div_title:
            vendor = x.find('h2')
            #print(vendor)
            for y in vendor:
                print(y.text)
                break
            break
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? Could you elaborate what are you trying to scrape from that URL ?

Answer (score 0):

To open each course page and get vendor name you can use this example:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = "https://cognitiveclass.ai"
r = requests.get(f"https://cognitiveclass.ai/search?q=data+science")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

for a_tag in soup.select(".courses-grid-item-info a"):
    print("href: ", base_url + a_tag["href"])

    request_href = requests.get(base_url + a_tag["href"])
    s = BeautifulSoup(request_href.content, "html.parser")

    print(s.select_one(".col-md-pull-4 h2").text)

    print("-" * 80)
```

Prints:

```
href:  https://cognitiveclass.ai/courses/course-v1:BigDataUniversity+DS0101EN+2016
Cognitive Class
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
href:  https://cognitiveclass.ai/courses/course-v1:CognitiveClass+DS0103EN+v3
IBM
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
href:  https://cognitiveclass.ai/courses/course-v1:IBMDeveloperSkillsNetwork+DS0105EN+v2
IBMDeveloperSkillsNetwork
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
href:  https://cognitiveclass.ai/courses/course-v1:FiresideAnalyticsNEB+DS0110EN+2019
National Energy Board of Canada 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
href:  https://cognitiveclass.ai/courses/course-v1:Cognitiveclass+PY0101EN+v2
Cognitiveclass
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
href:  https://cognitiveclass.ai/courses/course-v1:Lightbend+SC0105EN+v1
Lightbend
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
href:  https://cognitiveclass.ai/courses/course-v1:IBM+GPXX0IBEN+v1
IBM
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
href:  https://cognitiveclass.ai/courses/course-v1:IBM+GPXX0435EN+v1
IBM
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
href:  https://cognitiveclass.ai/courses/course-v1:IBM+GPXX0KY1EN+v1
IBM
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
href:  https://cognitiveclass.ai/courses/course-v1:IBM+GPXX01DCEN+v1
IBM
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
href:  https://cognitiveclass.ai/courses/course-v1:IBM+GPXX0ZMZEN+v1
IBM
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
href:  https://cognitiveclass.ai/courses/course-v1:IBM+GPXX0KHHEN+v1
IBM
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
href:  https://cognitiveclass.ai/courses/course-v1:IBM+GPXX04P5EN+v1
IBM
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
href:  https://cognitiveclass.ai/courses/course-v1:IBM+GPXX0PG8EN+v1
IBM
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
href:  https://cognitiveclass.ai/courses/course-v1:CognitiveClass+RP0101EN+v1
CognitiveClass
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```